# How to obtain your nodeID (QR code) in eclair-mobile?

Tags: lightning-network, eclair, lightning-nodes

I want someone to open a direct (no hops between us) channel to me in lightning (she will be the funder, I'll be the fundee). How can I get the QR code of my node in my eclair wallet to show to the funder? I don't find the UI/setting for it.

Answer (score 1):

Click the three dots in the top right corner, tap "Network Info".

[image: Eclair channels screen with burger menu open]

Your NodeId is visible on this screen

[image: Eclair Network Info screen]

Now, go to the URL `ip.tyk.nu` to find your IP address.

Now, in a Linux prompt (or WSL), install the PyPI `qrcode` package. On Ubuntu, it is available in the `python3-qrcode` package.

Now, execute this command (substitute the values you just learnt):

```
echo -n "<nodeID>@<IPaddress>:9735" | qr
```

The QR code is now visible in your terminal. If you want a real image, you can use `zbarimg` from the package `zbar-tools`.

Comment: I asked for a QR code...

Comment: @knocte QR generation commads appended

Comment: seems you're only answering to the title of the question, but not to the body of it :)